# ANR on Android 7.1.1 and above

Tags: android, performance, android-7.0-nougat

Before Android 7.1.1 my app used to be quite stable with ANR rate aroundd .6%. Now ANRs have increased drastically.

If I see reports on console I find below results

ANR below 6 is less than .4 %

Android 6 (all versions) 1.38%

**Android 7.1.1 18%**

Android 7.1.2 8.23

Android 8 10.02%

So, below are my questions/concerns

what platform changes may be reason for this trend in ANRs?

Has Anyone else found similar trends?

I will be more than happy to provide more information as required

Answer (score 0):

**Use of deprecated API**

In my experience I found that too much use of deprecated API causing ANR in latest release of android OS especially on Android 7  . You should try to avoid using deprecated apis. "Deprecated is one that programmers are discouraged from using, typically because it is dangerous, or because a better alternative exists. These API may work well in lower end device but not in higher end devices

Second one is **Too Much use of fragments in a Single Activity**

If you using one activity with lot of fragments  ,then this will also cause ANR in some devices. Because there is only one process and lot of task to be done on that process

based on my experience ,If you avoid these things then  you can significantly reduce ANR in Higher versions.